# Setprecision in a loop

Tags: c++, vector, struct

```
struct movie{
    int week;
    int month;
    int year;
    int rating;
};
```

In the loop below, I am trying to print out all the information in the vector of struct and I only want decimals in the ratings but this makes it so that there are decimals in all lines after the first iteration.

```
for(int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
    cout << info.at(i).week << endl;            
    cout << info.at(i).month << endl;
    cout << info.at(i).year << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << info.at(i).rating << endl;
}
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Also, if I'm not using pointers and haven't allocated dynamic memory, is it still possible to have memory leaks?

Comment: You could still have a memory leak because of badly written or poorly used third party libraries. But if you really have not allocated any dynamic memory (directly or indirectly) then a memory leak is impossible.

Comment: No I’ve only been using STL so does that mean no memory leaks?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to abuse the STL and leak memory, but if you're just writing normal code then using the STL will prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

It's tedious but you can save and restore the formatting flags

```
for(int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
    cout << info.at(i).week << endl;            
    cout << info.at(i).month << endl;
    cout << info.at(i).year << endl;
    ios_base::fmt_flags save = cout.flags();
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << info.at(i).rating << endl;
    cout.flags(save);
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned this in class yet so I doubt can use this. Is there another workaround?

Comment: I hope that you would get credit for using your initiative. The only alternative would be to set the formatting flags before every output.